# Como exlciur directorio al empaquetar con tar

Tags: linux, bash, script

No eh podido excluir un directorio al empaquetar un directorio con tar

Encontré estos ejemplos pero solo funciona para extensiones **tar.gz**

```
tar czvf post.tar.gz \
nivelador pruebas \
--exclude=nivelador/presentacion1 \
--exclude=pruebas/dir/archivo2
```

Y lo que necesito es que sea únicamente extensión **.tar** 
de manera que quede **post.tar**

De antemano muchas gracias.

Comment: Quita la opción `z` que es la que comprime

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Juan Diego.
Lo que estás haciendo al tirar ese comando es una doble compresión, primero en .tar (Tape Archive, antiguo archivador nacido con las cintas de copia), y después en .gz, propio de la herramienta de compresión gzip.
Para simplemente comprimir en tar debes hacerlo así:

```
tar cvf post.tar.gz \ nivelador pruebas \ --exclude=nivelador/presentacion1 \ --exclude=pruebas/dir/archivo2
```

Lo que haces es eliminar la opción z, evitando así la filtración del archivo a través de gzip. 
Por partes, la opción c crea un nuevo archivo; la v (de verbose) muestra en la salida (pantalla) la lista de ficheros procesados; por último, la opción f llama a los ficheros a comprimir.
Efectivamente, el comando extendido --exclude=PATRON excluye del procesado de tar los ficheros especificados.
Para listar el contenido del fichero .tar resultante del comando anterior, sin extraer ficheros, puedes usar:

```
tar tvf archivo.resultante.tar
```

Y para extraer su contenido (desempaquetarlo):

```
tar xvf archivo.resultante.tar
```

Suerte.

Comment: Me leo y corrijo: estrictamente, al armar tu fichero con extensión tar no lo comprimes, solo lo empaquetas; gzip sí comprime.

Comment: Muchas gracias :) Funciona perfectamente.

Comment: Un placer, Juan Diego